# How to use AngularJs scope in an external javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to draw a chart using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). The data comes from my API and I know the format is OK. I don't know how to pass the data retieved from the API to the javascript function.

In my controller, I got:

```
$http.get('/api/bilan').then(function(result) {
  $scope.finances = result.data;
});
```

And here is a snippet from where I should pass data:

```
var bilans = {
  labels: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
  datasets : [
    {
      data : [ TheDataFromTheApi ]
    }
  ]

};
```

What shoudl I put in *TheDataFromTheApi*? or how is the right way to do this?

Comment: Use Angular directive written for chart.js. http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  the existing library of [Chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) which has already converted code in angularise way.

Just you need to include `angular-chartjs.js`

And then inject to your model `angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js'])`

After that you can use it as attribute anywhere you want.

**HTML**

```
<canvas class="chart chart-bar" data="bilans.data" labels="bilans.labels" series="bilans.series"></canvas>
```

**CODE**

```
var app = angular.module("Bar_Chart", ["chart.js", "ui.bootstrap"]);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    // you can get this data by ajax
    var TheDataFromTheApi = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
    $scope.bilans = {
      labels: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
      data: [TheDataFromTheApi],
      series:["Months"]
    };
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6hJQKILLSY4gfUKFhiCZ?p=preview) For your code.

Comment: If I set **var finances = result.data** and try to use **data: finances** it doesn't work. I got _finances is not defined_

Comment: @LucienDubois updated sample code for your example and changed library, http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ this is quite good than the first one..

Comment: I got an error: Cannot read property 'global' of undefined inangular-chart.js .. Hum

Answer (score 0):

You should pass data into chart via an angular controller.

Call your service ($http.get ...) into the controller, and add its result in your data, then you may be able to create your charts.